# How can I handle sonar code smell for replacing @SpringBootApplication to importing list of beans manually

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

Hi I have got an issue while working with Spring boot. And when I am running solar analysis on my code I see one issue bothering me all the time.

> Blockquote

Consider replacing "@SpringBootApplication" by a list of beans imported with @Import to speed-up the start-up of the application".

> Blockquote

How Can i find list of beans that is required for my current project. is there any way to find which beans I have used so that I can manually import ?? please let me know

Comment: this might be helpful since it explains what teh @SpringBootApplication annotation is made-of: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

Comment: I suggest you ignore that warning. The gain isn't as large as that warning assumes. Component scanning is rather fast and importing all individual components is quite tedious and error-prone. If startup performance is really an issue there are better ways to improve your performance.

Comment: @M.Deinum This is something I cannot ignore as this is mandatory attempt as per our firm policy. Do u know how could we find beans that needs to be imported??

Comment: Please don't... Don't go down that path, it solves nothing and adds only complexity and will break future additions.

Comment: Ignore it! You might shave at most a few microseconds off the startup time, so the advice is bogus, plus it requires maintenance in case what's included in `@SpringBootApplication` changes.

Answer (score 0):

The key word here is "consider".  On many (most?) applications, you likely do not want to do this as it turns ComponentScan (automation) into a manual exercise and creates errors at runtime (on launch) if you get it wrong.  For smaller apps (microservices, etc) where the number of classes (and dependent libraries) are small, you should continue to use @SpringBootApplication.  Easier to maintain, at a small cost to boot-time performance.

If boot-time performance is a consideration *AND* as your application gets larger, and the number of dependencies grows *CONSIDER* switching.   In my situation, I had a large app (thousands of packages) with spring beans split across many, but not all of them.  Worse, they were hidden in apps-calling-jars-calling-jars, so it was a mess to begin with.  Proper organization would have likely helped avoid the issue.

Probably the right way is to treat the code as a graph.   In every Spring @Component (@Service, @Configuration, etc), you simply identify the other components it refers to.   So, if Bean1 has an "@Autowired Bean2", then Bean1 needs to @Import Bean2.  Bean1 may have multiple classes being imported.  Similarly, Bean1 and Bean7 might both @import Bean2.  You don't have to overthink it, just Import the beans you use in each class.  Go through your whole codebase, and you're good.  If you autowire to an interface, you likely need to @Import all the implementations (Spring will still sort out which one is injected).  When you're ready to try it out, take out the @SpringbootApplication, and replace it with just a "@SpringBootConfiguration + @EnableAutoConfiguration" (i.e. remove the @ComponentScan).  Your Application class will likely import your @Configuration classes, which in turn import the beans, etc, etc.  If you miss one, you will get (at container launch) a "Bean not found"(?) exception and it will crash - just add the @Import and try again.

This approach is pretty clumsy.  It means everytime you add an @Autowired, you have to add an @Import.  Manageable, but awkward.  The advantage is that Spring has *MUCH* less work to do when it spins up, so boot-time is improved.  Something to consider, but I don't think its a case of "always use @Import" (or the reverse).

Our Springboot app went from 65+ second launch to < 25 second launch by removing the hideous ComponentScan.  Your mileage will vary.

---

While @Import is a useful trick, the way-easier solution is to add a @SuppressWarnings("squid:999") to your Application class.  (sorry, cannot remember the actual error).  This is the programatic way of saying "I considered it, and rejected the idea".   Shuts Sonarqube up, and keeps the corporate-policy-police from knocking.

Answer (score -1):

Manually importing the beans is not recommended as it may be error-prone.
Although there is a way to suppress the warning by the Sonar Qube itself. On the Sonar Qube check the corresponding id which is displayed along with the warning.

then in the code place this annotation.

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:<SonarId>") // This is for suppressing sonar warning.
```

If that is allowed you can follow this way in order to get rid of warnings on the Sonar Qube.